# working with process, fork command

Tags: c, process, fork

im writing a simple code, making new process with fork, and then I want to see who is the child process and who is the father process.
As I know, the return value of fork to the child pc is 0 and to the father process is the pid number or child process.
somehow in both the child and the father I get 0.
can someone explain to me what is wrong with this code? 
thanks.

the code is :

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int status,i;

    if(childpid = fork() == -1){
        perror("fork err");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(childpid == 0){
        printf("child process, pid number is %d and returned value from fork is %d\n",getpid(),childpid);
    }
    else{
        printf("father process, pid number is %d and returned value from fork is %d\n",getpid(),childpid);
    }



}
```

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your first condition. The operator `==` has an higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. So in your `childpid` variable, you have the boolean result of `fork() == -1`. Add parenthesis to fix your problem:

```
if((childpid = fork()) == -1){
    perror("fork err");
    exit(1);
}
```

For more readability, put the assignment before the condition:

```
childpid = fork();
if(childpid == -1){
    perror("fork err");
    exit(1);
}
```

See [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
if(childpid = fork() == -1)
```

you assigned a value from condition  `fork() == -1` instead of a `pid`